# Too many files in p4 default changelist. How to let default changelist to show the recently used files?

Tags: perforce, perforce-client-spec

After I configure the perforce.
Under pending tab, there's default changelist. It shows "There are 86002 files in this changelist".
How can I solve this problem, let this default changelist only show the most recently changed files? Otherwise, each time, when I want to submit some files, I have to search them, it's really inconvenient. Thanks.

Comment: This is a pretty generic question. Have any more details?

Answer (score 2):

If you have files checked out that you haven't changed, just revert if unchanged.
With 86k files, I'm guessing you checked out an entire directory and probably didn't change every file.

Just revert unchanged files then try to submit again.